# Ajax call for the json response

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to apply ajax call for the response received from json.

Below my HTML.

```
<div id = "tabs">
<ul>
<li><A href="#ed_pro">Product Category</A> </li>
<li><A href="#ed_img">Add Image</A> </li>
<li><A href="#ed_txt">Add Text</A></li>
</ul>    
<div id="ed_pro">
</div>
<div id="ed_img">
</div>
<div id="ed_txt">
</div>
</div>
```

and

```
function handleTabSelect(data) {
    var items = '<ul>';
    $.each(data, function(i, object) {
        items += '<li><a id="main_cat" href=#>' + object.img_cat_des + '</a></li>';
    });
    items += '</ul>';
    $('#ed_img').append(items);
    flag = 1;
}

$('#main_cat').click(function() {
    var url1 = $(this).attr("href");
    alert(url1);
});

$("#tabs").tabs();

$("#tabs").bind("tabsselect", function(e, tab) {

    if (flag == 0) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '?q=design/lab_tab',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: 'slider_value=' + tab.index,
            success: handleTabSelect,
            error: function(xhr, status) {
                alert(xhr.statusText);
            }

        });
    }
});​
```

After getting the response from json,  the above script will append list of  as

```
<ul>
<li>
<a id="main_cat" href="#">Animals</a>
</li>
<li>
<a id="main_cat" href="#">Astrology</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

How I can apply further ajax call for .

On clicking the a href, it never invokes

```
$('#main_cat').click(function () {
var url1 = $(this).attr("href");
alert (url1);
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  <a id="main_cat" href="#">Animals</a>
  <a id="main_cat" href="#">Astrology</a>
```

- `Id` should be unique, you have multiple elements with the same `id` => **invalid HTML**
- use `on` to create a delegate event handler.

---

**Fixed markup:**

```
  <a class="main_cat" href="#">Animals</a>
  <a class="main_cat" href="#">Astrology</a>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('staticContainer').on('click', '.main_cat', function(){
    var url1 = $(this).attr("href");
    alert (url1); 
});
```

You should replace selector: `staticContainer` to fetch the closest **static**(exist on DOM ready) element that contains the new anchors.

Comment: Thanks.. I have achieved it with the below code $('#ed_img').bind('click', '.main_cat',function(event){
    var tg_element = $(event.target);
    var url1 = tg_element.attr("href");
    alert (url1);
 });

Comment: @PrabhuMK. cool, you can write that as an answer or accept this answer.Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @gdoron, I got it.

```
$('#ed_img').bind('click', '.main_cat',function(event){ 
  var tg_element = $(event.target); 
  var url1 = tg_element.attr("href"); 
  alert (url1); 
});
```

Regards,
Prabhu M K