# How to process json response from ajax call

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, rest, jersey

My webservice returns a JSON object like following

```
["abc","xyz","option_3"]
```

i.e. when I put this address in chrome browser `http://localhost:8088/rest/getOptions` I get above.

I am trying to read this in browser so that I can create a drop-down option... but I get nothing from below code to start with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        url="http://localhost:8088/rest/getOptions";
        var ajaxResult = null;
        function getData(yt_url){
            $.ajax
            ({
                type: "GET",
                url: yt_url,
                dataType:"json",
                async: false,
                success: function(response){
                    ajaxResult = response;
                }
            });
        }
        getData(url);

    alert(ajaxResult);

    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I always get `null` in alert box. I double checked with fiddler2 that webservice request/response is going through fine, I even can intercept json object between webservice and the browser.

I also tried

```
var obj = JSON.parse(ajaxResult);
alert(obj);
```

I get null again.

I have already looked at [Ajax call for the json response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261576/ajax-call-for-the-json-response) and similar questions. Please see my JSON is a bit different, so either those solution won't apply in my case or I didn't follow them.

I am a new to AJAX and Java script, please advise.

**EDIT:**
addding JERSEY webservice code which serves this  rest/getOptions end point

```
@GET
@Path("getOptions")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<String> getOptionsJson() {
    //build alloptions List<String>
    return alloptions ;
}
```

Comment: When you use `jsonp`, does your webservice wrap the data with information passed by the `callback` parameter?

Comment: Jon - he has Async set to false, his alert should work assuming the rest of the code is fine

Comment: no, it doesn't .. i was using json earlier, I start getting access error in chrome so I start using jsonp .. but I am going to edit the question, because I get same error when I use json in Firefox.

Comment: i can make async:true if that helps... I copied this example from somewhere.. I just want it to get to work with less work and follow best practices. Please help a noob here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

You edited the question; you can't use `dataType: 'json'` because of cross-domain issues that can only be overcome by either using a proxy on the same domain or via [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/).

When you use `dataType: 'jsonp'` you can't use `async: false`; this is because it doesn't really use `XMLHttpRequest` but uses the `<script>` tag to make it do cross-domain. I believe jQuery simply ignores the `async` setting without issuing a warning.

Therefore, the `alert()` will always be empty and you should move it inside the success callback.

To support JSONP your web service must wrap the returned data into a function call, identified by the `callback` GET parameter, e.g.

```
callback([1, 2, 3])
```

If your web service doesn't support this, as mentioned before, you would need to use [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/), e.g. add this response header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there way to make it work without touching the webservice code?

Comment: @Watt If the service doesn't provide JSONP support, you would have to use CORS.

Comment: If it is not too much trouble, can you please give me working version of code in question? Because, I am not sure how to do callback([]) or use CORS. I have added web-service side of code too for clarification.

Comment: @Watt Sorry, I'm not well versed in Java, but adding the response headers should be a simple configuration in your web server.

Comment: +1 for detailed and very useful info.. I got it working by modifying the web-service code as you mentioned.  The return is like this now return Response.ok(alloptions).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*").build();

Comment: @Watt Great! Please consider to accept this answer if you're happy with it :)

Comment: Sure! since I modified just webservice code, can you confirm HTML and JS code in questions is ok to use in production environment. Or it can use some improvement.

Comment: @Watt The code should work okay, though, synchronous ajax shouldn't be used because it degrades the user experience.