# Send data to server using ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, cordova

```
jQuery.ajax({
url:"http://192.168.0.74:8080/pimsdesign/JSONRequestHandler" ,
type: "POST",
data: {name: "amit", id:1 },
dataType: "json",
beforeSend: function(x) {
if (x && x.overrideMimeType) {
x.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
}
},
success: function(result) {
navigator.notification.alert(result);
}        
});
```

by using above code i am sending json data to server but server does not get data
How to solve it?

Comment: Looks like cross-domain issue.

Comment: @Jack how to resolve that?

Comment: If the service is under your own management you could return `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` response header, see also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15962196/how-to-process-json-response-from-ajax-call/15962224#15962224)

Comment: add an error handler an print out the error

Comment: @jack where to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * can you specify syntax for adding same

Comment: You add it in the response headers of your server.

Answer (score 0):

<del>try

    data: {name: "amit", id:1 },

=>

    data: JSON.stringify({name: "amit", id:1 }),</del>

Answer (score 0):

The following works in my PhoneGap applications: I assume you already made sure that your server is listening on port 8080 for that IP address

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: <some url>,
            data: { name: 'value'},
            dataType: 'json',
            timeout: 10000,
            async: true,
            cache: false,               
            headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
            success: function(data){
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

declare variable args in that pass the parameters you need to send to server.

Args = {

ModuleId: getUrlModuleId(),

EmpId: getUrlEmpId(),

LoginID: getUrlLoginID(),

RoleId: getUrlRoleId(),

CompanyId: getUrlCompanyId(),

GeoLocationId: getUrlGeoLocationId()

}

$.ajax({

url: "../HttpHandler/Test.ashx",  //handler path

data: args,                        // data's to be passed to server

cache: false,                      // cache false or true.If false it will wait for the response from the server.

success: function (data)           // response data should be convert to json before processing.

{

You can process the json data as .
   var name =data[0].columnname;

}

});