# Cross domain access and JSONP

Tags: javascript, http, cross-domain, jsonp

This is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16097763/jsonp-callback-function) about accessing resource cross-domain:

```
The XHR is constrained by cross-domain rules; to use JSONP you need to add a script element:

function func_callbk()
{
    console.log(arguments);
}

var s = document.createElement('script');
s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.src = 'http://abhishekprakash.com/script/example.json?callback=func_callbk';
var h = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
h.parentNode.insertBefore(s, h);
As pointed out by Ian in the comments, the proper response of your server should be something like this:

func_callbk('hello world')
```

**Questions:**

- If you cannot access resources cross-domain then this resource would not be accessible or at least the browser would not allow the domain to access the other domain: 
  `s.src = 'http://abhishekprakash.com/script/example.json?callback=func_callbk';` is that correct?
- A compliant server in the handshake should return a String of `func_callbk('hello world')` when the above resource is accessed?

Comment: Your question is not really clear. JSONP exploits the fact that generally browsers allow script sources to be in different domains than the host page. Yes, a JSONP-compliant server returns  its JSON response wrapped in a call to the function whose name you supply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers will allow `<script>` tags to refer to cross domain resources (along with a few other tags such as `<img>` and `<iframe>` and a few others, but will not allow ajax calls to reference cross domain servers without specific permissions being granted.

JSONP uses this capability given to `<script>` tags in order to work-around the cross domain issue.  It requires the destination server to support the JSONP way of doing things so the server must cooperate.  The results coming back from the JSONP call must actually be a script and it must call the function name reqeusted in the JSONP request URL and pass the desired data to that script.

You might want to read [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) describing how JSONP works.

And [this MDN same-origin article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) about the details of what is and isn't allowed for cross domain access.

If you're willing to require a newer browser and set up things appropriately on your server, you can use Cross Origin Resource Sharing.  Info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Comment: Oh! I mistook s.src = URL to a cross-domain resource access :-/

Comment: @xybrek - It is a cross domain resource access, but it is allowed from a `<script>` tag.

Comment: @xybrek - what only works for HTTP GET?  If I recall, you can do a form post to a different server, but not an ajax post.

Comment: Only through HTTP GET we can retrieve JSON documents from other domain?

Comment: @xybrek - well, what I've said above is only through the use of a `<script>` tag (which happens to use an HTTP GET).  You can read a lot more about what is and isn't allowed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Comment: how can it be useful for the other HTTP methods which is used in Rest API's too like PUT, POST and DELETE?

Comment: i'm trying to build a restful backend that is intended to be accessed by different domains or apps, so I asked whether put,post and delete can also take advantage of this

Comment: @xybrek - you can't use JSONP with anything other than a `<script>` tag so thus it is only used with a GET.  If you want cross-domain access to other types of commands, then you'll either need a proxy server on the page's domain or you can require support for a newer cross origin access standard such as CORS which you can read about [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Comment: @xybrek - or you can surface everything in your API via JSONP GET, but put the verb into your API so the server knows which the OP wanted to do from an API argument, not from the request type.

Comment: I wonder how twitter can do POST for this api: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/friendships/create where I think this can be accessed from other domain

Comment: @xybrek - That API is probably meant to be used by a server or app (not a browser) which is not subject to the same-origin restrictions.  Same-origin restrictions only apply to javascript code being run from within a browser web page.

Comment: Yup I know, but if the request originates from javascript then it subject to same-origin policy right? Actually apps that will use the rest api would be browser-based apps. Front-end apps that calls into backend with javascript.

Comment: @xybrek - Yes, if the request originates from the javascript of a browser web page, it is subject to the same origin-policy.  It is the browser that implements and enforces that restriction on the javascript that it runs in normal web pages (add-ons may not be as restricted).  You could run javascript in a node.js app or python on your desktop or PHP on your server and freely use that API without any origin restriction.