# my callback not working for json data from cross domain

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, callback, jsonp

I am using ajax call for getting json data from cross domain url using "jsonp" datatype but error function calling. I can see json data in mozilla developer -> Network-> response that is coming. below is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
url : 'https://www.example.com /fetchdata?param=1',
type : 'POST',
crossDomain : true,
dataType : 'jsonp',
headers : {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' : 'POST'
        },
jsonpCallback : 'callbackdata',
success : function(data) {
            alert("success");
        },
error : function(xhr, status, error) {
    console.log(error);
    alert("fail");
        },
});
});
function callbackdata(response) {
        alert(response)
     }
```

getting following error:

```
Error: callbackdata was not called
Stack trace:
.error@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:2:1821
b.converters["script json"]@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:4:16101
uc@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:4:7333
x@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:4:10747
.send/c@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:4:15393
n.event.dispatch@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:3:6392
n.event.add/r.handle@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:3:3202
 CORS:25:7
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
```

and response in mozilla daveloper-> network

```
{"datapoints": [{"record_timestamp": "10-09-2016 05:30","data": {"temperature": {"id": "3","param_name": "temperature","value": "28.6","unit": "celsius"}}}]}
```

json data is not wrappig up with jsonpcallback. Please help me to find solution.

If I try to make the ajax call with "json" as dataType instead of "jsonp", the server responds

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.example.com/fetchdata?param=1.(Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the server you are requesting from that needs to set the CORS headers up, so whatever your `example.com` is needs to have their server set up to serve the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` header. Putting it in your AJAX request will not have an effect.

Answer (score 0):

The server you are requesting data from returns JSON, not JSONP. The server must support JSONP, which requires it to return JavaScript code, not pure JSON.

For example:

JSON is:

```
"{\"message\":\"hello world\"}"
```

JSONP is:

```
callback({message:"hello world"})
```

The server will return the JSONP script when the 'callback' URL argument is provided (which jQuery does for you).

Unless this particular server supports this, your callback will not be called.

Although not a jQuery question, [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16097763/5459839) covers same subject.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I understand JSON and JSONP difference but if data(json) coming from third party url so how can I change to JSONP and how server support JSONP . Please help. I am not getting anything on google.

Comment: The third party server must support it. It will recognise the call you make if it does. Since it doesn't, and you get this error, it means that third party does not support JSONP

Comment: ok. we pretend server doesn't support JSONP. so what is the alternative possible in this scenario. can you please give me solution.

Comment: There is no solution if you don't control the server or cannot contact the owner to change their settings. Sometimes the correct answer to a question is just that.